# How to develop UIMockup in iOS sdk?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, mockup-tool

Any one have idea about UIMockup in iOS sdk? I visited [Appcooker site](http://www.appcooker.com) and also [This fluidui site](https://www.fluidui.com)
 could any one tell me how it actually works and how can I submit that app to app store?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd want to find a Mockup tool that supports exporting projects as Xcode projects. It doesn't appear that either of those products do that.

This one claims to support it, but I have no idea if it works: http://interface2.lesscode.co.nz

Honestly I wouldn't recommend putting too much time into this because I don't think the results would be good. If you want to turn a mockup into an app you should hire a developer.